# Slidetoggle same in two site but not working in one site

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I use slidetoggle in one site , working perfectly. when use in other site not working. These two site have same theme , same jquery version , almost everything same, but in other site not working. Anyone can help?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cefyQ.png)

```
jQuery(".tabs ul li").click(function(){
                    if (jQuery( ".tabs ul li" ).hasClass('ative-tab')) {
                        jQuery( ".tabs ul li" ).removeClass( 'ative-tab');
                        };
                        jQuery(this).addClass("ative-tab");
                    var my_value=jQuery(this).text();
                    jQuery('#active-tab-mobile').text(my_value);
                    jQuery('#active-tab-mobile1').text(my_value);
                            jQuery('.my-mobile ul').slideToggle (300);
                });
```

I use slidetoggle in one site , working perfectly. when use in other site not working. These two site have same theme , same jquery version , almost everything same, but in other site not working. Anyone can help?

Comment: ```.hasClass('ative-tab')``` i'm guessing this should be ```active-tab```?
Please share relevant HTML in a snippet so we can reproduce.